# Method returns String and null at the same time.

Tags: java, string, null

I'm learning Java on my own since a month, and want to create Hangman Game with GUI. I've spent 2 days trying to figure out whats going on, but cannot find the solution myself nor any help from google.

I think the problem is (except for the noobish approach for sure :P) that `displayWord()` method returns String AND null at the same time, but don't know how to fix that and why exactly it's giving me a null...

I'd be really grateful if someone would be so kind and point out the error.

```
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Game {
    private CLabel guessRemainLabel = new CLabel("GUESSES REMAINING: ");
    private CTextField guessRemainField = new CTextField("");
    private CLabel wordLabel = new CLabel("WORD TO GUESS: ");
    private CTextField wordField = new CTextField("");
    private CButton[] buttons = new CButton[26];
    private CButton guessButton = new CButton("GUESS");
    private String qwerty = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
    private char chosenChar;
    private String buttonText;

    private String wordDisplayed;
    private String wordPicked;
    private String wordChecked;
    private String word;
    private boolean buttonPressed = false;

    public Game() {
        // Frame settings
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hangman");
        frame.setSize(900, 600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("", // layout constrains
                "[] [] [] [] [] [] []", // columns constrains
                "[]40[]10[]30[] [] []"); // rows constrains
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(layout);

        frame.add(panel);

        // Remaining guesses
        panel.add(guessRemainLabel, "span 2");
        panel.add(guessRemainField, "span 7, alignleft, wrap");

        // Word
        panel.add(wordLabel, "span 7, center, wrap");
        wordField.setText(displayWord());
        panel.add(wordField, "span 7, center, wrap");

        // Buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new CButton("" + qwerty.charAt(i));
            buttons[i].addActionListener(buttonListener);
            if (i == 6 || i == 13 || i == 20) {
                panel.add(buttons[i], "wrap");
            } else {
                panel.add(buttons[i]);
            }
        }
        panel.add(guessButton, "span");
        guessButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(224, 50));
        guessButton.setBackground(new Color(243, 156, 18));

        newGame();

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Buttons' actions
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (CButton button : buttons) {
                if (e.getSource().equals(button)) {
                    buttonText = button.getText();
                    chosenChar = button.getText().charAt(0);
                    buttonPressed = true;
                    checkWord();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void newGame() {
        pickWord();
        checkWord();
        displayWord();
    }

    public String pickWord() {
        WordReader wordReader = new WordReader();
        wordPicked = wordReader.getRandomWord();
        word = wordPicked;
        return wordPicked;
    }


    public String checkWord() {
        if (!buttonPressed) {
            // replace all letters with dashes
            // word.replaceAll(".","_");
        } else {
            if (word.toUpperCase().contains(buttonText)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                    if (word.toUpperCase().charAt(i) == chosenChar) {
                        // show letters if char found
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // count lives left 
            }
        }

        wordChecked = word;
        return wordChecked;
    }

    public String displayWord() {
        wordDisplayed = wordChecked;
        return wordDisplayed;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Anti-aliasing
        System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "on");
        System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Game();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to post MCVE code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also, not really related to your problem, but in general I'd avoid mixing graphics & game logic. Just a tip.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Does it run? Just trying to get more idea to help

Comment: How do you know its return is null and a String? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Frame runs correctly but displayWord() doesn't display anything. Checked with System.out.println it returns two values - word AND null

Comment: Not really related since it is about commented code, but `word.replaceAll(".","_");` should be `word = word.replaceAll(".","_");` (remember that strings are immutable so methods can't change them, all they can do is create new string based on old one).

Comment: Why are `pickWord(), checkWord(), displayWord()` all of return type `String`, shouldn't they be `void`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the easiest way to figure out your problem. You say that your `displayWord()` method is returning String and null at the same time (although that's not really possible). What this means is that:

```
public String displayWord() {
    wordDisplayed = wordChecked;
    return wordDisplayed;
}
```

In the method above, `wordChecked` must be `null` because then `wordDisplayed` would become `null` and thus the method would return `null`, creating your problem.

I would go through your code to where you set the value for the variable `wordDisplayed` and figure out if you access it BEFORE you set it, because accessing before setting a private instance variable is going to give you a `null` value.

**EDIT:** This is also a major problem. Most of your method return a `String`, but when you run them, you also setting the returned value to a variable. I would advise that you either chance the return type to `void`, because there's no reason to have the return type as `String` if you aren't going to use the returned value.

Comment: Deleted call to the wordDisplayed() from Game(), called wordField.setText() in wordDisplayed() instead, and it's working... Also changed return types to void. Thanks for tips!

Answer (score 0):

From what you have, I believe your problem is within the method you described, displayWord(). In this method you don't initialize your wordChecked variable at all, that might throw an exception since you are using it to set wordDisplayed.